# Meu logo em bootstrap está demasiado grande e os restantes menus têm um grande espaço vazio entre eles

Tags: c#, html, css, mvc

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"> <img src="~/Content/Images/logo_branco.gif"/> </a> 
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Reunião", "Index", "Reuniao")</li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Configurações <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Empresas", "Index", "Empresa")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Salas", "Index", "Sala")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li
```

[image: Imagem]

Comment: Adicione no atributo img: class="img-responsive"  e insira um width.